# Problem with the display of custom listview (webview in my listview)

Tags: android, listview, webview

I am having an issue that make me crazy

I have a listview with WebView inside. So I created a custom listview.
The WebView forbid me to click so I created a webviewclicklistener.

My problem was that when I display some images, my webviews are "shaking" as if it wants to load the image a thousand times. 
In fact I discovered that the height size of some elements change like every seconds, that give a feeling of shake.

The only way I found to fix it is to give a layout:height value for my listview.
My new problem is that when I put for exemple 600dip, I have a scrollbar, but I can't look at the end of my listviews. 
If I put like 1000dip, I don't have scroll bar and I can't see the end of my list neither.

Here is my layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@drawable/woodbackground"
android:layout_weight="1">
<TextView android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Question" android:textSize="30px"></TextView>
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">
    <WebView android:id="@+id/wvplquestion" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"></WebView>
</ScrollView>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Select Answer" android:textSize="30px"></TextView>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/lvquestion" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="600dip" android:prompt="@string/selectp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And my custom listview layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="3dip">
<WebView android:id="@+id/weblistview" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></WebView>
```

Thanks for your  help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can try to change your listview layout height. Instead of wrap content, put a fixed height. I don't know if it will be working, but you can try it. I'd a problem similar to yours and I solved it like this.
I hope it will work. Good luck ;)

Comment: Yeah that's what I did. It's not the best solution cause I have various content but it's ok

Answer (score 0):

Seems it mostly happens when several webviews contained into one scrollview. Seems at least first webviews should have fixed height.